# Exim4 how to deny unauthenticated MAIL FROM from local domains

Tags: ubuntu, exim

I have an Ubuntu exim4 installation. I experienced many invalid mail where an anonymous sender sends email to a valid address presenting itself as the same valid address.

For example, my exim is configured for domain "mydomain.com" and this unauthenticated message is accepted:

```
MAIL FROM: info@mydomain.com
RCPT TO: info@mydomain.com
DATA
From: info@mydomain.com
....
```

It looks strange to me, because I expect that Exim by default refuses such spoofing emails.

This is default contant of acl/30_exim4-config_check_mail configuration file:

```
### acl/30_exim4-config_check_mail
#################################

# This access control list is used for every MAIL command in an incoming
# SMTP message. The tests are run in order until the address is either
# accepted or denied.
#
acl_check_mail:

  accept
```

How can I force to check that MAIL FROM address of local domain must be authenticated?